# Accessing Qunit Module setup variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

*Hi Guys,
Currently I'm testing my javascript code with Qunit Testing framework. I am not able to access my QUnit.module setup variables in QUnit.test function.*

```
QUnit.module( "Module A:Build Notes",{
    setup: function () {
        this.inputsticky = $("input[name=stickyinput]");
    }
});
QUnit.test("Test Case 1",function (assert) {
    assert.expect(1);            
    orangeClick(); //changing color                                                    
    assert.equal( this.inputsticky.css('background-color'),'rgb(255, 165, 0)', "orange Function passed !" );
});
```

*Result:
this.inputsticky is undefined*

Comment: That won't work, QUnit doesn't work that way. But more importantly, why are you doing that versus just selecting the element in the test?

Comment: @jakerella I need to use that input element for many test cases. So to reduce some redundancy I'm jus storing the element in the variable(this.inputsticky) and call the same wherever necessary.

Comment: Yeah... but QUnit doesn't work that way with `this`, I think. You can simply define a variable outside of the module instead. I'll add an answer for this

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, if you just want to hold onto the HTML element you can create a variable outside of the module entirely. Using `this` isn't really going to work (that I know of):

```
(function() {
  // put things in an IIFE to prevent data leakage

  let inputElement;  // define the variable at a higher scope

  QUnit.module( "Module A:Build Notes",{
    setup: function () {
      // now we can set the variable's value for use in all later tests
      inputElement = $("input[name=stickyinput]");
    }
  });
  QUnit.test("Test Case 1",function (assert) {
    assert.expect(1);            
    orangeClick(); //changing color                                                    
    assert.equal( inputElement.css('background-color'),'rgb(255, 165, 0)', "orange Function passed !" );
  });

})();
```

Comment: Hi Jakerella,  

I have implemented the same in my qunit file mate. Still its not working. If you have some time can you please look into my code. I have updated my github link below:

https://github.com/haripery/unitTest_JS_Qunit

Comment: If that isn't working, then the problem isn't about selecting the element. Try logging out the value of the `.css()` call.

Comment: Hi jakeralla,
I have replaced setup with beforeEach with your idea and now it finally works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {


  var inputElement;  // define the variable at a higher scope

  QUnit.module( "Module A:Build Notes",{
    beforeEach: function () {
      // now we can set the variable's value for use in all later tests
      inputSticky = $("input[name=stickyinput]");
    }
  });
  QUnit.test("Test Case 1",function (assert) {
    assert.expect(1);            
    orangeClick(); //changing color                                                    
    assert.equal( inputSticky.css('background-color'),'rgb(255, 165, 0)', "orange Function passed !" );
  });

})();
```

Comment: Qunit has replaced the setup with following:
before (function)        Runs before the first test.
beforeEach(function) Runs before each test.
afterEach (function)   Runs after each test.
after (function)           Runs after the last test.